# Datatablesを使用して、JsonデータをTableに表示する方法が知りたいです。

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

まず、現在の実装状況です。

HTMLではカラム名のみを設定しています。
javascriptでは、すでにjsonを取得しています。
jsonの内容は
{"NO":"1", "cal1":"taro", "cal2":"1234", "cal3":"jap", "cal4":"30"}の構成で、複数来ます。
取得したデータ要素はそれぞれ「No.←NO、列１←cal1、列２←cal1、列３←cal1、列４←cal1」というようにカラムに追加していきたいです。

※また、最終的にはTableにチェックボックスカラムを追加する予定です。

このように、JsonをTableに反映させたいのですが、方法が分かりません。ご教授をお願いします。

```js
＊java script
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "http://url";
   // Jsonデータ取得
    $.get(url, function (jsonData) {

    });

    $('#example').dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        iDisplayLength: 100,
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        bSortClasses: false,
        bFilter: true,
        bLengthChange: true,
        bJQueryUI: true
    });
});
```

```html
*HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=s-jis" />
    <title>DataTables example</title>
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "./css/styles1.css";
        @import "./css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css";
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="dt_example">
    <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>列１</th>
                <th>列２</th>
                <th>列３</th>
                <th>列４</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

    </table>
    <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

画面イメージです。
[image: イメージ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htmlのtableに入れる必要がそもそもありません。
DataTablesのdataオプションとcolumnsオプションを設定すれば直接jsonを読んでくれます。
下記ページのData source types: object の項を参照してください
http://www.datatables.net/manual/data

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
参考にして実装したところ、解決することが出来ました。